# Modelling an airplane with a irregular shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I'm trying to model this plane, which is the ME 262(1941) : [image: ME 262]

As you can see, the plane's nose is in a conic shape; however, the rest of the body is triangluar-ish. As a result, I'm having some problems modelling the plane since the transition from the conic shape nose to the triangular body is weird. I need the two to transition properly and smoothly. Could somebody help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by adding a edge around the "triangluar-ish" part. Add a circle **with the same number of vertices as the outer edge**.
Then open up the specials menu with <kbd>W</kbd>, and find the *[Bridge Edge Loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops)* command.

In this picture I have a mirror modifier so I only have to model half of the plane.
[image]